# Image prediction based on CNN Model always return similar (and centered) result

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, classification

I'd like to ask you a question about a model on which I've breaking my head for a few days...
I am trying to write a CNN model to predict a result between 2 classes (similar to cat or dog issue).
My code does recognize the pictures in Train and Validation folders, and also the pictures to predict in the Test folder, however the result to all the predicted pictures are almost the same and with very low accuracy (0.49), (attached a picture).[photo_of_the_results_from_sample_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCKfe.png)

I tried to change the optimizer between adam, SGD, RMSprop
I tried to change the loss to sparse categorical
I tried to change the metrics to confusion matrix (which it did not even recognize for some reason)
and nothing worked......

could somebody help me fix my code please?
Thank you so much in advanced!!

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, 
MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import adam, SGD, RMSprop
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# 1 - Load data
train_dataset = "\\Pictures_Dogs_DataSet\\Train1/"
validation_dataset="\\Pictures_Dogs_DataSet\\Validation1/"
test_dataset = "\\Pictures_Dogs_DataSet\\Test/"

# 2 - Create network layers
image_width = 200 
image_height = 200

model = Sequential()

# add convolutional layer (CNN)
# 32 X 32 pixel matrix
# 3 layars (RGB)
# 3 X 3 sliding matrix
# a pixel value for each colour is between 0-255
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape= 
(image_width,image_height,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
# Add another block for more abstract features
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(image_width, 
image_height,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
# Add another block for more abstract features
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape=(image_width, 
image_height,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
# Add another block for more abstract features
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3), input_shape=(image_width, 
image_height,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

# Let's DropOut some connections to avoid over-fitting.
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))


# Using the prediction model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

# used to rescale the pixel values from [0, 255] to [0, 1] 
interval
datagen =ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# automatically retrieve images and their classes for train 
and validation sets
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dataset,
        target_size=(image_width, image_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dataset,
        target_size=(image_width, image_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

#  3 - Train
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=10,
        epochs=1,  
        #just 1 epoch to practice and make sure it works#
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=5)


#evaluate the accuracy of the model
model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator,verbose=0)

#save modules
#model.save('model.h5')

# 5 - predict
test_generator =datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory=test_dataset,
        target_size=(image_width,image_height),
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=32)

print(model.predict_generator(test_generator))
```

Comment: during training your validation accuracy is super low, no amount of parameter tuning will make up for your tiny amount of data. train it for more than 10 steps and see where the validation accuracy can get without overfitting.

Comment: Hey @chris, 
My true data is fairy big (around 17K for training and 7K for validation), I only posted with the above (small data) to get to the same (similar and centered) result faster.
Though I believe the problem lies somewhere else..

Comment: @RonJ You have a typo in `rescale` argument: change `1255` to `255`.

Comment: @today
Thx for reading my code. I correced the typo (both here and on the original code)
problem remained the same..